# Abort trap: 6 - Libwebsocket Mac

Tags: c, macos, sockets, websocket, libwebsockets

Good afternoon, I am trying to compile and execute this code. It turns out that it compiles and executes perfect, but when it comes to hitting from the FRONT (I am using Angular), it breaks me when I enter a nickname, that is, the server connection is aborted, but anyway in the database it it stores me with errors, for example, if in the nickname I put "Juan" it is stored in the database as "Juantofks =" and I get the error of ABORT.

Anyone know why this happens?

I am using the libwebsocket library for the server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libwebsockets.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#define SIZE 100 // Create a stack with capacity of 100 elements long stack[SIZE];

// Initially stack is empty int top = -1;

MYSQL *conn; MYSQL_RES *res; //    MYSQL_RES *res2; MYSQL_ROW row; //  MYSQL_ROW row2;

char *server = "localhost"; char *userdb = "root"; char *password = "111222"; /* set me first */ char *database = "chat";
#define MAX_STRING 128 char query[MAX_STRING] = {0}; char messagefull[MAX_STRING] = {0}; char query2[MAX_STRING] = {0}; char username[MAX_STRING] = {0}; char iscontact[MAX_STRING] = {0}; char message[MAX_STRING] = {0}; char contact[MAX_STRING] = {0};

/* Function declaration to perform push and pop on stack */ void push(long element); int  pop();

int explode(char ***arr_ptr, char *str, char delimiter) {   char *src
= str, *end, *dst;   char **arr;   int size = 1, i;

  // Find number of strings   while ((end = strchr(src, delimiter)) != NULL)
    {
      ++size;
      src = end + 1;
    }

  arr = malloc(size * sizeof(char *) + (strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof(char));

  src = str;   dst = (char *) arr + size * sizeof(char *);   for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
      if ((end = strchr(src, delimiter)) == NULL)
        end = src + strlen(src);
      arr[i] = dst;
      strncpy(dst, src, end - src);
      dst[end - src] = '\0';
      dst += end - src + 1;
      src = end + 1;
    }   *arr_ptr = arr;

  return size; }

static int callback_http(struct lws *wsi,
                         enum lws_callback_reasons reason, void *user,
                         void *in, size_t len) {    return 0; }

static int callback_dumb_increment(struct lws *wsi,
                                   enum lws_callback_reasons reason,
                                   void *user, void *in, size_t len) {

    long wsi_adress = wsi;
    conn = mysql_init(NULL);

    /* Connect to database */
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server, userdb, password,
                                      database, 8889, NULL, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }
    switch (reason) {
        case LWS_CALLBACK_ESTABLISHED: // just log message that someone is connecting
            printf("connection established\n");

            break;
        case LWS_CALLBACK_CLOSED: {
            snprintf(query, MAX_STRING, "DELETE FROM users WHERE token=%lu", wsi_adress);
            if (mysql_query(conn, query)) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
            }



                //RESET CONTACT
                char contact[MAX_STRING] = {0};
                char reset[MAX_STRING] = {0};
                char *out = NULL;
                snprintf(query, MAX_STRING, "SELECT * FROM users");

                if (mysql_query(conn, query)) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
                    exit(1);
                }
                res = mysql_store_result(conn); //                res = res2;
                char value[10];
                char *eptr;
                long long wsi_long;
                while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) {
                    strcpy(value, row[1]);
                    /* Convert the provided value to a decimal long long */
                    wsi_long = strtoll(value, &eptr, 10);
                    free(out);
                    push(wsi_long);
                }
                mysql_free_result(res);

                snprintf(query, MAX_STRING, "SELECT * FROM users");

                if (mysql_query(conn, query)) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
                    exit(1);
                }
                int i = 0;
                for(i = 0; i < top + 1;i++){
                    snprintf(reset, MAX_STRING, "reset");
                    len = strlen(reset);
                    out = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + len + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING));
                        //* setup the buffer*/
                    memcpy (out + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING, reset, len );
                        //* write out*/
                    lws_write(stack[i],  out + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING, len, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
                    free(out);
                }
                res = mysql_store_result(conn);
                int j = 0;
                while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) {
                    for(j = 0; j < top + 1;j++){
                        snprintf(contact, MAX_STRING, "contact:%s", row[2]);
                        len = strlen(contact);

                        out = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + len + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING));
                        //* setup the buffer*/
                        memcpy (out + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING, contact, len );
                        //* write out*/
                        lws_write(stack[j],  out + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING, len, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
                        free(out);
                    }
                }
                pop();

                mysql_free_result(res);
            break;
        }

        case LWS_CALLBACK_RECEIVE: { // the funny part
            // create a buffer to hold our response
            // it has to have some pre and post padding. You don't need to care
            // what comes there, lwss will do everything for you. For more info see
            // http://git.warmcat.com/cgi-bin/cgit/lwss/tree/lib/lwss.h#n597   


            unsigned char *buf = (unsigned char*) malloc(LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + len +
                                                         LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING);
            //memset(&buf,'\0', sizeof(buf));
            int i;

            // pointer to `void *in` holds the incoming request
            // we're just going to put it in reverse order and put it in `buf` with
            // correct offset. `len` holds length of the request.
            for (i=0; i < len; i++) {
                buf[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + (len - 1) - i ] = ((char *) in)[i];
            }
             //GUARDAR USUARIO !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            int n;
            int len;
            char *out = NULL;
            char listContact[MAX_STRING] = {0};
            /* send SQL query */
            char **arr;
            char **arr2;
            char isUserNameString[MAX_STRING] = {0};
            char contact[MAX_STRING] = {0};
            strncpy(isUserNameString, (char *) in, 11);
            isUserNameString[11] = '\0'; //
            if(strcmp("firstnamews", isUserNameString) == 0) {
                explode(&arr, (char *) in, ':');
                snprintf(username, MAX_STRING, "%s",  arr[1]);
                free(arr);
                snprintf(query, MAX_STRING, "INSERT INTO users (name, token) VALUES ('%s', '%lu')",  username, wsi_adress);

                if (mysql_query(conn, query)) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
                    len = strlen(mysql_error(conn));
                    out = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + len + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING));
                    //* setup the buffer*/
                    memcpy (out + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING, mysql_error(conn), len );
                    //* write out*/
                    lws_write(wsi,  out + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING, len, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
                    free(out);
                    break;
                }


                //RESET CONTACT
                char contact[MAX_STRING] = {0};
                char reset[MAX_STRING] = {0};
                char *out = NULL;
                snprintf(query, MAX_STRING, "SELECT * FROM users");

                if (mysql_query(conn, query)) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
                    exit(1);
                }
                res = mysql_store_result(conn); //                res = res2;
                char value[10];
                char *eptr;
                long long wsi_long;
                while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) {
                    strcpy(value, row[1]);
                    /* Convert the provided value to a decimal long long */
                    wsi_long = strtoll(value, &eptr, 10);
                    free(out);
                    push(wsi_long);
                }
                mysql_free_result(res);

                snprintf(query, MAX_STRING, "SELECT * FROM users");

                if (mysql_query(conn, query)) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
                    exit(1);
                }

                res = mysql_store_result(conn);
                int i = 0;
                for(i = 0; i < top + 1;i++){
                    snprintf(reset, MAX_STRING, "reset");
                    len = strlen(reset);
                    out = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + len + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING));
                        //* setup the buffer*/
                    memcpy (out + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING, reset, len );
                        //* write out*/
                    lws_write(stack[i],  out + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING, len, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
                    free(out);
                }
                int j = 0;
                while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) {
                    for(j = 0; j < top + 1;j++){
                        snprintf(contact, MAX_STRING, "contact:%s", row[2]);
                        len = strlen(contact);

                        out = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + len + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING));
                        //* setup the buffer*/
                        memcpy (out + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING, contact, len );
                        //* write out*/
                        lws_write(stack[j],  out + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING, len, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
                        free(out);
                    }
                }
                pop();

                mysql_free_result(res);
                break;
            }

            //ENVIAR MENSAJE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            explode(&arr2, (char *) in, ':');
            snprintf(iscontact, MAX_STRING, "%s",  arr2[0]);
            snprintf(message, MAX_STRING, "%s",  arr2[2]);
            snprintf(contact, MAX_STRING, "%s",  arr2[1]);
            free(arr2);
            snprintf(query, MAX_STRING, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='%s'",  contact);
            if (mysql_query(conn, query)) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
            }
            res = mysql_store_result(conn);
            char value[10];
            char *eptr;
            long long wsi_long;
            while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) {
                strcpy(value, row[1]);
                /* Convert the provided value to a decimal long long */
                wsi_long = strtoll(value, &eptr, 10);
            }
            mysql_free_result(res);
            snprintf(query, MAX_STRING, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE token='%lu'",  wsi);
            if (mysql_query(conn, query)) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
            }
            res = mysql_store_result(conn);
            while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) {
                snprintf(messagefull, MAX_STRING, "from:%s:%s", row[2],message);
                len = strlen(messagefull);
                out = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + len + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING));
                //* setup the buffer*/
                memcpy (out + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING, messagefull, len );
                //* write out*/
                lws_write(wsi_long,  out + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING, len, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
                free(out);
            }
            free(buf);
            break;
        }
        default:
        break;
    }
    mysql_close(conn);
    return 0; }

static struct lws_protocols protocols[] = {
    /* first protocol must always be HTTP handler */
    {
        "http-only",   // name
        callback_http, // callback
        0              // per_session_data_size
    },
    {
        "dumb-increment-protocol", // protocol name - very important!
        callback_dumb_increment,   // callback
        0                          // we don't use any per session data
    },
    {
        NULL, NULL, 0   /* End of list */
    } };

int main(void) {
    // server url will be http://localhost:9000

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);

    /* Connect to database */
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server, userdb, password,
                                      database, 8889, NULL, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }
    snprintf(query, MAX_STRING, "TRUNCATE TABLE users");

    if (mysql_query(conn, query)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }
    mysql_close(conn);
    int port = 9000;
    struct lws_context *context;
    struct lws_context_creation_info context_info =
    {
        .port = port, .iface = NULL, .protocols = protocols, .extensions = NULL,
        .ssl_cert_filepath = NULL, .ssl_private_key_filepath = NULL, .ssl_ca_filepath = NULL,
        .gid = -1, .uid = -1, .options = 0, NULL, .ka_time = 0, .ka_probes = 0, .ka_interval = 0
    };
    // create lws context representing this server
    context = lws_create_context(&context_info);

    if (context == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lws init failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("starting server...\n");

    // infinite loop, to end this server send SIGTERM. (CTRL+C)
    while (1) {
        lws_service(context, 50);
        // lws_service will process all waiting events with their
        // callback functions and then wait 50 ms.
        // (this is a single threaded webserver and this will keep our server
        // from generating load while there are not requests to process)
    }

    lws_context_destroy(context);

    return 0; }

/**  * Functiont to push a new element in stack.  */ void push(long element) {
    // Check stack overflow
    if (top >= SIZE)
    {
        printf("Stack Overflow, can't add more element element to stack.\n");
        return;
    }

    // Increase element count in stack
    top++;

    // Push element in stack
    stack[top] = element;

    printf("Data pushed to stack.\n"); }


/**  * Function to pop element from top of stack.  */ int pop() {
    // Check stack underflow
    if (top < 0)
    {
        printf("Stack is empty.\n");

        // Throw empty stack error/exception
        // Since C does not have concept of exception
        // Hence return minimum integer value as error value
        // Later in code check if return value is INT_MIN, then
        // stack is empty
        return INT_MIN;
    }
    return stack[top--]; }
```

Comment: I don't see how this warrants a [macos] tag? Also it seems a little unreasonable to expect someone to find the bug in your ~400 line application. You need to produce a minimal, reproducible example. That said; if "Juan" is becoming ""Juantofks =" it suggests a memory error, most likely an unterminated string

Comment: Yes, it is a memory or buffer error, maybe I could extend the buffer range to see if it manages to enter the string perfectly. Anyway I ran this same code on Linux and compiled without problems, it is clearly an operating system error.

Comment: This is classic undefined behaviour: you have a memory error, and the compiler/runtime on different systems gives you a different result. That is not an "operating system error". I suggest learning how to use a debugger. You can also try address sanitizer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think that adding something in the code can be fixed? I was searching the internet for solutions but I didn't find any effective.